# use React-typescript with custom typescript transformers (using ttypescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-conversion, react-typescript

I have a typescript transformer I regularly use in the backend (Nodejs typescript), and I want to use it in the frontend too (React typescript). for that, I need to use [ttypescript](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript) wrapper so the transformers will be enabled.

backend npm start command is `npx ttsc`
frontend npm start command is `react-scripts start`

How can I use the ttsc command in the React app?

As for the record, the transformer used is a run-time type-checker, very useful!